# Running command on each line in file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, xmlstarlet

I have `FramesList.txt`, the file holds 5 `.xml` filenames. There isn't a path generated because the list is being created by an `xml ls > FramesList.txt` command.

I want to run an `xmlstarlet` command on each `.xml` file listed.

```
FramesList.txt
FR0391W.xml
FR0921S.xml
FR0193A.xml
FR0192B.xml
FR0132E.xml
```

How would that look? Is it a loop?

Comment: Although this question might get answered, you should show your research and what you have tried. Now it looks like you expect us to fix your problem.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please
[edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code that you
are having problems with, then we can try to help with the
specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Sorry everyone, I didn't even know what command to use here.. Thanks to andlrc who showed me xargs. Total newbie here, didn't know about xargs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `xargs`:

```
xargs < FramesList.txt -n 1 xmlstartet
#       ^               ^   ^
#       |               |   Command to run
#       |               Max number of arguments (xmlstartet will be called for
#       |               each line in input file)
#       Input file
```

Comment: I recommend to also use the `-r` option, just in case one day the input file is empty.

Comment: @andlrc This was helpful, although when I outputted the xmlstarlet to .csv I lost my formatting. It would turn it into one long line, instead of having breaks. Instead I went with the following: `cat FramesList.txt | xargs xmlstarlet -n > FrameInfo.csv`   not sure why that -n had to be there, but its what brought back the right formatting.

Comment: Seems like this command strings all arguments together on one line, and you need to include `-L1` to get one command per line.

Answer (score 4):

```
while  read -r line
do

xmlstarlet "$line"

done <FramesList.txt
```

Comment: You should usually `read -r` to not treat <backslash> in any special way. For OP's case it might not be a problem though. And also remember to quote variable expansions: `xmlstartet "$line"` or it will undergo wordsplitting

Answer (score 0):

I think most XML Starlet commands accept more than one file as a parameter, and since your input list is small, you could also write

```
xml COMMAND $(<FramesList.txt)
```